# Problem while finding the perimeter of a cardioid.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area, curves, plane-curves

**Pre-Requisite for My Problem**
There's this cardioid curve and I need to find it's perimeter. The equation given by my teacher is
$$R=a(1+\cos\theta)$$
Here,
$R$ : the distance to and part of the curve from the origin.
$\theta : $ the angle made by $R$ w. r. t. positive x-axis.

He said when we are given an equation like $r=f(\theta)$, then in order to obtain the perimeter of the desired curve we need to apply this formula.
$$S=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{\bigg(r^2+\big(\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}\big)^2\bigg)}\space d\theta$$
where
$S :$ perimeter of the curve
$\alpha:$ initial angle $R$ makes with positive x-axis
$\beta:$ final angle $R$ makes with positive x-axis

Now, when I apply all these to find the perimeter of the cardioid where $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.

**My Problem**
Now, I am really banging my head for the integration part. It turns out that when you integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$, the result is $ZERO!$. But if we apply the Property of Definite Integral and multiply $2$ with the whole integration and then integrate the function from $0$ to $\pi$, then we get the result as $8a$.
Can anyone please point out the mistake in my approach?

Comment: type instead of posting pictures

Comment: If you used the identity $\sqrt{1+\cos \theta}=\pm2\cos(\theta/2)$, the sign depends on where $\theta$ lives (positive for $0<\theta<\pi$, and negative for $\pi<\theta<2\pi$).

Comment: it's very hard as I said, otherwise I surely would have. But was there any problem regarding the understanding of this problem, please suggest so that I can make some possible improvements as I really need to get this problem done, it's apain now

Comment: $\pm\sqrt 2$ above on the right, sorry...

Comment: If you would have written the integration steps, we could have pointed out where is your mistake. As @DavidMitra suggested, your error is that you used only one form of the half angle identity for cosine function. That formula is valid only when the cosine is positive. Otherwise when cosine is negative you say it is equal to a positive quantity (the square root). So the approach is correct, but you need two integrals, one from $0$ to $\pi$ and one from $\pi$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @DavidMitra,Thank You very very much sir

Comment: @Andrei Thank You too sir...

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: You can tell something's wrong with the answer zero since the integrand is never negative.